# How do I run Roblox Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, chromebook, crossover

I have tried WINE and CROSSOVER and they didn't work. Wine just shows an uninformative error and crossover does the same, so I uninstalled both.

I am using an Acer Chromebook R 11

Is there any way to get Roblox Studio working on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

From the latest test result, Roblox Studio probably doesn't work on Wine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180301050848/https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26443

I assume you have Ubuntu installed on your Chromebook. You could try running Roblox Studio in a virtual machine, but the program might detect the VM as "cheating" and refuse to run.

Comment: virtural machine please explain how do i use that ima try it im willing to try anything at this point

Comment: and which one should i use